# Right rotation operation

Tags: c++, rotation

```
int main()
{
    int shiftSteps, newposition;
    int numbers[10], numberscopy[10];
    cin >> shiftSteps;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        cin >> numbers[i];

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        numberscopy[i] = numbers[i];

    //----------------------------------------

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        newposition = (i + shiftSteps) % 10;
        numbers[newposition] = numberscopy[i];
    }

     for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        cout << numbers[i] << "  ";
}
```

I wrote this code to rotate 10 numbers to Right with auxiliary array **"numberscopy"**, but i want to rewrite the code without auxiliary array and i don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without auxiliary array, you can make use of reversal algorithm to rotate array by "shiftSteps".
It involves following three steps,

- reversing array from 0 to sizeOfArray-1
- reversing array from 0 to shiftSteps-1
- reversing array from shiftSteps to sizeOfArray-1

Here's final code,

```
void reverseArray(int numbers[], int begin, int end) 
{ 
    while (begin < end) 
    { 
        swap(numbers[begin], numbers[end]); 
        begin++; 
        end--; 
    } 
} 

void rightRotate(int numbers[], int shiftSteps, int sizeOfArray) 
{ 
    reverseArray(numbers, 0, sizeOfArray-1);
    reverseArray(numbers, 0, shiftSteps-1);
    reverseArray(numbers, shiftSteps, sizeOfArray-1);
    
} 


int main()
{
    int shiftSteps;
    int numbers[10];
    cin >> shiftSteps;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        cin >> numbers[i];

    rightRotate(numbers, shiftSteps, 10);
 
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        cout << numbers[i] << "  ";
}
```

[Source](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/program-for-array-rotation-continued-reversal-algorithm/) for more info.

Comment: This is an interesting approach, though a bit inefficient. You could still use `std::reverse` instead of writing the reversal function yourself.

Comment: @cigien yes we can use `std::reverse` and  even then `std::rotate` will likely be faster as I recall it will benefit from memmove() optimizations, but I think the author was looking for an answer from an algorithmic perspective. Btw this approach was used in early UNIX editors for moving text.

Comment: @cigien The "three reverse" rotation actually has good performance and is used in the libstdc++ and Microsoft C++ standard library implementations.

Comment: @Blastfurnace Oh, that's very interesting, I didn't know that. Naively, I would expect that to have worse performance. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @cigien Reversal is very cache friendly for contiguous containers. The three most common rotation algorithms are Gries-Mills Block Swap, Juggling (GCD), and Reversal. All can be found in C++ standard library implementations depending on the iterator types.

Comment: @Blastfurnace Oh, so `rotate` is probably as efficient, *because* it uses reversal under the hood. That makes sense.

Comment: @cigien The [Gries-Mills 1981 paper](https://ecommons.cornell.edu/handle/1813/6292) describes all three algorithms that are still used to this day. I think it's a good read.

Comment: @Blastfurnace That looks like a good paper. Thanks so much for the link.

Answer (score 5):

You can rotate the array in-place, i.e. without using an auxiliary array with [std::rotate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate) which is a standard algorithm.

```
std::rotate(numbers, numbers + shiftSteps, numbers + 10);
```